# IPhone 5S Mobile Safari Hyperlinks not 'clickable'

Tags: html, css, iphone, hyperlink, href

I've been working on a website ( http://www.clicks1.co.uk/#Contact ). However I've come across a bug in which many of the 'click' interactions on the page don't work on some Iphones but do on others. I've found it to work perfectly on an Iphone 5, but not on an Iphone 5s.

Specifically in the contact area, the hyperlinked facebook, twitter, and google+ images do not open the links when tapped on an iphone 5s.

It was my thinking that perhaps there's some kind of element overlaying the hyperlinks blocking any attempt to press them. Still not sure why this would only be an issue specific to some iphones and not others.

Comment: You can use Safari's web inspector on a connected iPhone or the iOS Simulator. Start there. http://moduscreate.com/enable-remote-web-inspector-in-ios-6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to create an invisible absolute positioned div with a high z-index. This div was then positioned above the original hyperlink element and given a href link.

```
<a href="example.com" style="width: 60px; height: 60px; position: absolute; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0); z-index: 9999;"></a>
```

If like me you want to use this solution over dynamically sized images/text then I found giving width and height parameters % (eg width: 40%) values allowed them to resize with the elements they were above.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when there are other 'invisible' elements on top of the hyperlinks.

Use the browser's developer tools to inspect the link and see which HTML element it selects. If it selects one other than the hyperlink, than chances are that element is superimposing.

Sometimes a 'clear:both;' on a mediaquery is all it takes to fix problems like this.